# How could Belarus know that a dissident was travelling on a plane not bound to their territory?

Tags: international-relations

Belarus has been [accused](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-57224452) of using a fake bomb scare to divert a Ryanair plane in order to capture a wanted person on board.

I am aware that the lists of plane passengers are shared between security agencies in order to purportedly screen suspect terrorists. But are they also shared with countries which are not part of the Europol or NATO blocks? Are they shared with all the possible countries via Interpol? Otherwise how can a country like Belarus know who is flying on a plane which is not going to land in their territory?

I would like to make clear that I am not asking whether they received a tip off. As I said above passenger data are shared via official channels. Are those channels so open that officials in Belarus could have known the names of the people on board? If getting this information via official channels is not possible an acceptable answer could just clarify this point.

Comment: @JeffLambert I'll edit my question to add a clarification. I am not asking about tip off, but about how travel data are shared via official channels.

Comment: Even with that edit the question seems about the sharing of information via law enforcement channels (As that is what I am guessing is the method for sharing that info) and not about politics itself.

Comment: This would be better on Aviation.SE

Comment: @JoeW It is international security cooperation, international law has not been completely established yet, it is still undefined and left to international politics.

Comment: @JonathanReez I was writing my comment above when you added yours, but you can consider it also an answer for you.

Comment: Considering we don't even know (or at least you don't include in your question) about how they got this information there could be no cooperation agreements at all and it could just be good old fashioned spy work. For all we know they had people watching his every move and were able to determine what flight he got on and that is how they got the info.

Comment: @Joe W My question is "Do the official channels allow Belarus to gather this information or not?". Judging from your comments you don't know the answer. So why do you keep commenting?

Comment: Are you suggesting they got this information through official channels?

Comment: @JoeW I am not suggesting anything I am asking.

Comment: Some articles suggest Interpol may have been used, but I don't know enough about Interpol to answer the questions. In any case, for Belarus to access data through "official channels," a treaty would be involved, For that reason, I changed the tag to [international-relations].

Comment: The Ryanair CEO is [claiming that there were Belarusian KGB agents on the flight](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/24/world/europe/belarus-ryanair-plane-journalist.html), which would suggest that they were surveilling Roman Protasevich in Greece. I'm not sure if there's public evidence beyond Mr. O’Leary statement yet, though

Comment: I read that Protasevich stated in an interview in Greece that he felt like he was under surveillance. It could be as low-tech as his movements being monitored.

Comment: I am seeing more evidence that it was a simple matter of agents on the ground and had nothing to do with sharing of information. https://www.businessinsider.com/belarus-diverted-plane-kgb-agents-onboard-ryanair-ceo-2021-5

Answer (score 6):

[Ryanair has accused Belarus](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/24/world/europe/belarus-ryanair-plane-journalist.html) of using spies to monitor Roman Protasevich.

Ryanair Cheif Executive O'Leary states "We believe there were some K.G.B. agents offloaded at the airport as well". Of 126 original passengers only 121 arrived at their destination, implying that four other passengers were agents monitoring Roman.

Comment: I believe Roman's partner was also taken off the plane - implying three agents

Comment: O'Leary is assuming that they were agents because they didn't get back on the plane when the bomb scare was solved. But, is he sure that they remained in Belarus voluntarily. Isn't it possible that the authorities got the chance to grab several dissidents?

Comment: @FluidCode Why try to discredit the most logical explanation for the problem? It seems to me the easiest way for them to know what flight he was on was by manual tracking of him and getting on the same flight.

Comment: @JoeW A logical explanation is not an evidence. O'Leary assumption is still an assumption.

Comment: @FluidCode You have no evidence against it and have not even attempted to provide any. It seems like you are looking for a specific answer that information was shared and want to ignore any evidence that they used spies to track the target and boarded the flight in an attempt to capture him. There are many sources reporting on this as the most likely reason for this all happening.

Comment: @JoeW Please respect the scientific method. If someone makes a claim, they should provide some evidence. otherwise people are allowed to doubt the claim. Trying to shift the burden of the proof on those who doubt the claim is called the charlatan method.

Comment: @fluidcode For security reasons, people aren’t allowed to just get off the plane without telling anyone. In a normal situation, if someone disappeared from a plane, you’d ground it out of the suspicion that they planted a bomb and then escaped before it could detonate. It seems extremely unlikely that an ordinary passenger would be allowed to simply walk off during a security operation like this

Comment: @divibisan People were forced to disembark to check the plane. Was Ryanair staff kept always together with the passenger? Can they tell what happened in the transit area?

Comment: @FluidCode Scientific method? This answer has a link to an article that is describing the claim while you just make a counter claim that it can't be true. This answer is just stating what others believe along with the evidence that they used to support that claim. Besides this type of claim has nothing to do with the scientific method.

Comment: @FluidCode They should have been, but I have no idea if that was the case in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers indicate, it's reported that Belarus had one or more spies onboard the flight. Further evidence to support that are messages Protasevich sent to colleagues claiming that he was being followed as he was boarding the flight.

Colleagues of Protasevich claim that he had sent them messages claiming that he was being followed by someone he believed to be a Belarusian KGB agent as he was boarding the plane bound for Lithuania. As reported in the [the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/may/24/belarus-seizure-blogger-ryanair-flight-us-outcry):

> According to colleagues, Protasevich had sent them messages claiming he was being followed by a man in the departure lounge in Athens he suspected was a Belarusian KGB agent. The man was said to have been behind him in the queue to board. He was said to have tried to take a photo of his documents before asking Protasevich a “stupid question” in Russian and leaving.

Two images of the alleged messages were [tweeted by Bianna Golodryga](https://twitter.com/biannagolodryga/status/1396517734624677889) who is a journalist for CNN:

> This is so chilling, the telegram messages Roman Protasevich sent to colleagues prior to boarding the Ryanair flight in Athens about a suspected KGB agent he thought was following him.
>
> “He’s attempting to photograph my documents.” “He’s at my gate.”
>
> (Via @tvrain)
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> https://twitter.com/biannagolodryga/status/1396517734624677889

---

> I would like to make clear that I am not asking whether they received a tip off. As I said above passenger data are shared via official channels. Are those channels so open that officials in Belarus could have known the names of the people on board? If getting this information via official channels is not possible an acceptable answer could just clarify this point.

I don't think airlines normally provide passenger information on flights flying over Belarus. If such information had been shared or would normally be shared in situations like these, it would have come up in news reports on the incident.

Note also [this question on Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/163892) which is very similar to yours. Specific to the question of flying over, [the accepted answer by Tor-Einar Jarnbjo states](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/163894):

> As jcaron already pointed out in a comment, airlines are also required to file a passenger manifest to get clearance to fly through US airspace. As far as I know, the USA is the only country requiring so.

Answer (score 0):

Belarus used a spy to observe him.

Comment: I would include a link to a news story with that information

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Because he's Clint Eastwood!